# Merging XSLTs into one flle and calling each template separately matching specific content

Tags: xslt

I've the below Sample XMLs.

**XML1**

```
<root num="1">
 <abc></abc>
 <cde></cde>
 <def></def>
</root>
```

**XML2**

```
<root num="2">
 <xyz></xyz>
 <cft></cft>
 <vft></vft>
</root>
```

**XML3**

```
<root num="3">
 <dfg></dfg>
 <mnb></mnb>
 <gft></gft>
<root>
```

And i have 3 different XSLTs, each corresponding to XML.

I want to achieve the below.
Make a single XSLT and call the template based on the root number. something like the below.

```
<xsl:if test="root[@num="1"]>
<!--Call the template matching root 1-->
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="root[@num="2"]>
<!--Call the template matching root 2-->
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="root[@num="3"]>
<!--Call the template matching root 3-->
</xsl:if>
```

I just want to put all the XSLTs in a single XSLT, please let me know how can i do this.

Thanks

Comment: added an example, is this everything you need?

Answer (score 1):

You can use  element.

The  element contains rules to apply when a specified node is matched.

The match attribute is used to associate the template with an XML element. The match attribute can also be used to define a template for a whole branch of the XML document (i.e. match="/" defines the whole document).

Note:  is a top-level element.

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="cd">
  <p>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="title"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="artist"/>
  </p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="title">
  Title: <span style="color:#ff0000">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/></span>
  <br />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="artist">
  Artist: <span style="color:#00ff00">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/></span>
  <br />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This was taken from http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_template.asp

Comment: Here i've the XSLTs already written and they are in different files, i want them to be in one file and be called based on the root number.

Comment: Yes copy the stylesheet content from the other files into the one containing the template elements. Put each file content (not the whole file just the transforms) into each template element that match the right element id.

Comment: There is an example on w3schools but when i get to my pc i will put one here

Comment: This is not what i needed I've basically multiple documents, have to run this on all.

Comment: You can copy the xslt from other files into the other file keeping it all to one file. Do you want to merge them or not? Can you be more clear on what need please.